# Is Broadcast variable in spark moved to each executor or each nodemanager in YARN?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In YARN how is broadcast variable distributed across nodes. I am confused if it goes to each executor in Nodemanager or only copy on each node manager in cluster.

Please let me know about it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Broadcast variables in Apache Spark is a mechanism for sharing variables across executors that are meant to be read-only.

In order to understand Broadcast variable behavior please understand how the Spark life cycle works

1. Spark driver is started by YARN
2. It creates DAG for the Job
3. Job contains of Mapping an reducing tasks
4. These mapping and reducing tasks are ran in an Executor (i.e. a separate JVM process with its own thread pool)
5. This executor get its own copy of Broadcast variable at the time of initialization. The broadcast variable is distributed by Spark, not Yarn.

**Step 3** will be repeated task based on volume of data or if its a Spark streaming job but there will always be one copy of **broadcast variable** and stay with the executor till it goes down.

If by node manager you are referring to Spark Worker nodes then I don't think Spark Worker nodes needs broadcast variable so they might not keep any copy of it.

Node manager (i.e. Spark worker) is responsible for,
 - allocating the required resources
 - registering executor to the driver
 - maintaining the Driver - Executor communication

Comment: I had same confusion.. Now I understood.. good explanation.. :)

Answer (score 0):

When there are multiple executors running on the same node, each executor will create its own copy of the broadcast variable. Therefore, the number of broadcast variables created will be equal to the number of executors running on the node.

For example, if there are 3 executors running on the same node and a broadcast variable is created, then there will be 3 copies of the broadcast variable created, one for each executor. This is because each executor runs in its own JVM and has its own memory space. Therefore, each executor needs its own copy of the broadcast variable to ensure that changes made to the variable in one executor do not affect the variable in other executors.